# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule creating infinite loop(500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need foo.com/bar return foo.com/bar.html content.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L]
```

it works.

but, if visit foo.com/bar/ or foo.com/bar/baz, web server will return 500 Internal Server Error.

```
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795804 2020] [core:error] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795817 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3833): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00121: r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795820 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795823 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795826 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795829 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795832 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795834 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795837 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795840 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795842 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz.html
[Tue Sep 08 19:09:20.795853 2020] [core:debug] [pid 25600:tid 140626049849088] core.c(3840): [client 101.80.56.171:62155] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /bar/baz
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` doesn't behave well. You may use this rule instead using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```